# Echoing out variables in a function

Tags: php

I am trying to returning a string like this.

```
 $col="<td><input ".$name." type='".$field['1']."' ".$id."  ".$class." value='".eval( '?>    '.$row[$field["2"]] .'<?php ')."'".$size." ".$maxlength." ".$disabled." ".$readonly." /></td>";
```

I need

```
value='".eval( '?>'.$row[$field["2"]] .'<?php ')."'
```

to be evaluated  after the string is returned into the page so i can use my sql call

```
 $row = $core->getRowById("email_users", $user->userid,"userid");
```

I include the row here.

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled" size="55" value="<?= $row['username'];?>" class="inputbox" name="username">
```

It would then evaluate this

```
$row['username'];
```

How can I go about doing this? Do I use eval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your point:
You can't do that, PHP doesn't work in a multipass way. Your eval would be a plain string in output. You have to use either POST or GET back to this page, check whether $_POST or $_GET exists, and act accordingly.